# Is Latex already built into Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, latex

I am a physics student who needs to produce lab reports in LaTeX format. It would really help if I could do this from my own laptop.

Comment: As a "how to istall" question this may be better on Super User

Answer (score 5):

No, you'll need to download the MacTeX package and use it. Mac OS X has no built-in LaTeX authoring support.

Comment: you can download the latest from http://www.tug.org/mactex/2009/

Answer (score 1):

As a physicist, I use [`fink`](http://www.finkproject.org/) for all my unix package management needs. Install fink, go to a terminal and type

```
$ fink install texlive
```

and you are good to go (well, open another terminal to get paths refreshed) just like you are on any other unix box.

Answer (score 1):

As another alternative, you can use [Mac Ports](http://www.macports.org/).  This is basically a port of a Linux package manager and many packages.  If you are going to need other packages (gnuplot, ImageMagick, etc.) using this or fink is the way to go.  It will also allow you to easily keep the packages updated.

Answer (score 0):

If the full [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2009/) distribution is too large for your system, my next recommendation would be the smaller [BasicTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2009/morepackages.html) distribution.